# Why it is rendering first and then updating the state later in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to fetch the data when the button is clicked but the Newsitem component is running first and then updating the value of data_grabber. That means it is displaying the defalut values rather than the data that I fetched from the newsapi. After displaying the newsitem component with default values, data_grabber is updating the fetched data.
What can be the solution?

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [input_data, setInput_data] = useState("");
  const [btn_data, setBtn_data] = useState("");
  const [data_grabber, setData_grabber] = useState([]);
  
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar
        input_data={input_data}
        setInput_data={setInput_data}
        setBtn_data={setBtn_data}
        btn_data={btn_data}
        data_grabber={data_grabber}
        setData_grabber={setData_grabber}
      />

      {data_grabber? data_grabber.map((news_data)=>{
        return(
          <NewsItem news_data={news_data}/>
        )
      }):<div>No data available</div>}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function Navbar(props) {
  const onClicker = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.setBtn_data(props.input_data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetcher = async () => {
      const link = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${props.btn_data}&apiKey=API_KEY`;
      const raw_data = await fetch(link);
      const data = await raw_data.json();
      console.log(data);
      props.setData_grabber(data.articles)
    };
    fetcher();
  }, [props.btn_data]);
  

  return (
    <div>
       <form className="d-flex">
              <input
                onChange={(e) => props.setInput_data(e.target.value)}
                value={props.input_data}
                className="form-control me-2"
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                aria-label="Search"
              />
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-success"
                type="submit"
                onClick={onClicker}
              >
                Search
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

NewsItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class NewsItem extends Component {
    render() {
      const {title, description, url, urlToImage} = this.props.data
      const defaultImage = `https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEh20SgNNsDlKyWWmB7XgB5SfFY10M6CqJAq93HwGtssTn2cWz6w9zHPjXf91WwoWr27QeaC4HsGv2NxPOXUdvk6xodUojnw8rUuAkEMY3Qb4ucoVpN3nSyF8JW_xVDWa2aSMEWH387hPsfouSJyClLNburIcDbXIeJamuTHwiSvw4hdNnqeeICcvg1wrQ=w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu`
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="card">
          <img src={urlToImage?urlToImage:defaultImage}  className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{title?title:'No title available'}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">
              {description?description.slice(0, 50):"no description available"}...
            </p>
            <a href={url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"className="btn btn-primary">
              read more
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you updating the dataGrabber?

Answer (score 0):

One fix could be to
make a variable of the updated state:
in the UseEffect ,
add :

```
const updated = data.articles
props.setData_grabber(updated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `data_grabber` array is empty or not and then do the rendering inside `App` component as follows.

```
{
  data_grabber.length > 0 ? (
    data_grabber.map((news_data) => {
      return <NewsItem news_data={news_data} />;
    })
  ) : (
    <div>No data available</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 { data_grabber !== undefined && data_grabber.length > 0 ? data_grabber.map((news_data)=>{
        return(
          <NewsItem news_data={news_data}/>
        )
      }):<div>No data available</div>}
```

Check data_grabber is undefined or empty.

Then, fix NewsItem props.data like this.

```
export default class NewsItem extends Component {
    render() {
      const {title, description, url, urlToImage} = this.props.news_data
```

also fix here in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetcher = async () => {
      const link = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${props.btn_data}&apiKey=c990aa0235da4635997afd1f7459860c`;
      const raw_data = await fetch(link);
      const data = await raw_data.json();
      console.log(data);
      if(data.articles){
        props.setData_grabber(data.articles)
      }
    };
    fetcher();
```